# What to return if a try catch fails in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and mainly programmed Java before.
The Problem is I have this:

```
private fun createUrl(stringUrl: String): URL? {
    try {
        return URL(stringUrl)
    } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
        return null
    }
}
```

That is just the style I was used to in Java. I would just check if the URL is null in the next method, but what is the Kotlin equivalent? What would I return in Kotlin?

Greetings

Comment: What is your question? your code is already in kotlin

Comment: The function looks ok to me. But Kotlin has safe calls so you don't have to check for null in the next step. `createUrl("hx.malf0/$md!")?.openConnection()` see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I wrote the code in Kotlin, but I simply wasn't sure, if I were following Kotlin's Design Language by returning null. I am sorry for that unclear Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already wrote this in Kotlin, so not entirely sure of your whole question.
However, returning URL? is perfect.

Then you can do

```
mWebURL.set(createUrl(myString))
```

or

```
  mWebURL.set(createUrl(myString)?: "alternativeURL")
```

if you have an observable that is ok accepting null.

Or if you need to take an action on it, you can simply do

```
createUrl(myString)?.nextAction() //only occurs if not null
```

or you can use

```
createURL(myString)?.let{
    //will happen if not null
}
```

or

```
createURL(myString)?.apply{
    //will happen if not null
}
```

or of course simple

```
if(createUrl(myString) == null){
    //will happen if not null
}
```

Comment: Ah ok yes, I wrote the code in Kotlin, but I simply wasn't sure if I was following Kotlin Design Language by returning null. Anyways thanks for making that clear! :)